# Verification of understanding: Cantor's diagonalization

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I think I understand but need verification. And I haven't seen this asked in this particular way. So Cantor's diagonalization proves that a given set (set of irrationals in my case) is uncountable.

My question for verification is: I think that what Cantor's argument breaks is the surjection part of countable sets by creating a diagonalisation function of a number that fits the set criteria, but is perpetually not listed for any bijective ordering of the uncountable set. Am I understanding this correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thanks so much!!